# text over figure in latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am trying to add a simple figure into my latex code .I have this code :

```
\begin{figure}[H]
 \resizebox{40pt}{!}{ 
\centering \includegraphics{FigureStereo.jpg}} 
\caption{Epipolar Geometry} 
\label{fig:cclogo} 
\end{figure}
```

with this however the text comes on top of the image and also image is not centered .What am I doing wrong?Hopefully this is not a repeated question coz I did do a quick check on related posts.
Edited 
Here is the preamble

```
\documentclass[draftthesis,tocnosub,noragright,centerchapter,12pt,]{uiucecethesis09}


\makeatletter

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}  % for figures
\usepackage{graphicx}  % another package that works for figures
%\usepackage{subfigure}  % for subfigures
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for math spacing
%\usepackage{amssymb}  % for math spacing
%\usepackage{url}  % Hyphenation of URLs.
\usepackage{lscape}  % Useful for wide tables or figures.
\usepackage[justification=raggedright]{caption} % makes captions ragged right - thanks to Bryce Lobdell
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% Uncomment the appropriate one of the following four lines:
\msthesis
%\phdthesis
%\otherdoctorate[abbrev]{Title of Degree}
%\othermasters[abbrev]{Title of Degree}

\title{}

\author{}
\department{}
\degreeyear{}

% Advisor name is required for
% - doctoral students for the ProQuest abstract
% - master's students who do not have a master's committee
\advisor{}

% Uncomment the \committee command for
% - all doctoral students
% - master's students who have a master's committee
%\committee{Professor Firstname Lastname, Chair\\
%        Professor Firstname Lastname} % etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `center` environment for centering, wrapping it around both the image box and the caption:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\resizebox{40pt}{!}{\includegraphics{FigureStereo.jpg}}
\caption{Epipolar Geometry}
\label{fig:cclogo}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Note, though, that LaTeX can sometimes be pretty stubborn about how it lays out pages where floating elements are concerned. The `h` option is more of a guideline than a guarantee. In some cases you might be better off not using a floating `figure` environment and instead inserting the graphics and text directly.

Also, you're better off asking this sort of question over at the [TeX StackExchange site](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @walkytalky-tried exactly what you said but still it has text over the image and its not centered.

Comment: @Manish What happens if you skip the `resizebox` and just `\includegraphics[width=40pt]{FigureStereo.jpg}`?

Comment: @walkytalky:-Nope .tried that ..doesnt help. Text still comes on top of the figure.

Comment: @Manish In that case there's definitely something amiss, this is very routine stuff. Do you have anything unusual in your preamble?

Comment: @walkytalky :-I've edited above to include the preamble.It is a pretty standard template used by the college.Shouldnt have anything unusual

Comment: @Manish Well, it doesn't look strange, but I'd probably start by switching to one of the standard document classes (`article` or maybe `letter`) and commenting out everything except the most basic packages -- maybe `graphicx` and `amsmath`. If that doesn't fix it, you may need to troubleshoot your LaTeX install. If it does, add stuff back in until the problem recurs. And definitely post to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want something like

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{figs/foo}}
\caption{Caption Goes Here}
\label{fig:cclogo}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thanks Niraj, That makes the figure go onto a new page and still not be centered .That is not really what I am looking for.What I want is the figure be placed between the text ( may be where the portion occurs in the tex code ) and be centered.So if I were to do a vertical traversal of the page I'd have some text , the figure (with no text around it ) and then more text before reaching the end of the  page

Comment: Just reduce the width (or height of the figure). e.g., `width=\0.25columnwidth`. I believe your figure might be large enough that its being treated as a float. Your latex build should be spitting out some warnings about it.

Comment: - I reduced the size to 20pt but it still shows text above the image and again not centered.